# Proper way to store a dict as a column value in parquet format using pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have a requirement to store a nested list of json objects in a column by doing a JOIN between two datasets related by one-to-many relation.
Example: stackoverflow posts (each question can have one or many answers), answers should be populated against each question as a nested list of dict.

I am able to achieve this perfectly using pandas. I can store the output as parquet and also load it back again using pandas. However, due to performance reasons I am using pyspark.

But, when I store the nested list of objects column using pyspark, I am not able to load it back using pandas, which makes me wonder if I can store it differently such a way that I can load it back using pandas.

The error I get is this:

> pyarrow.lib.ArrowNotImplementedError: Not implemented type for Arrow
> list to pandas: map<string, string>

If I convert the pyspark dataframe to pandas and store it as parquet file, I don't run into this error. So, I believe parquet has the necessary support to be able to store the data that way I want (so that I can load these list(dict) columns using pandas).

Below is my pyspark code

```
        answers_dicted = answers_df.withColumn("dict",
        create_map(create_map_args(answers_df))
    ).select(["Id", "ParentId", "dict"])

    # group answers by questions
    print("Grouping answers by questions")
    answers_grouped = answers_dicted.groupby("ParentId").agg(collect_list("dict").alias("answers"))

    # populate questions with answers 
    print("Adding answers to questions")
    questions_df = questions_df.join(answers_grouped, questions_df.Id == answers_grouped.ParentId, "left").select(questions_df["*"], answers_grouped["answers"])
```